# NetTrain question: Inconsistent numbers of examples provided to ports

Tags: neural-networks

New to neural network models in Mathematica and working my way through documentation and examples:

Have a model where I would like to map real number vectors of length 15 to predict an output vector of length 108. I am using a MeanSquaredLossLayer to calculate the error between the network output and the target data (weeklyReturns).

Here is my code:

```
Dimensions[features]
{15, 1611}
Dimensions[weeklyReturns]
{108, 1611}

coder = NetChain[{LogisticSigmoid, 15, DropoutLayer[0.1], 
   LogisticSigmoid, 108, LogisticSigmoid, 108}]
      trainer = 
 NetGraph[{coder, MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, {1 -> NetPort[2, "Input"]},
   "Input" -> 15]
trainer = NetInitialize[trainer]

 {trainedNet, lowestVal} = 
 NetTrain[trainer, <|"Input" -> features, 
   "Target" -> weeklyReturns|>, {"TrainedNet", 
   "LowestValidationLoss"}, TargetDevice -> "GPU", 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 500000, Method -> "ADAM", 
  ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1], BatchSize -> 64]
```

Getting the following error:

```
During evaluation of In[377]:= NetTrain::invinlen: Inconsistent numbers of examples provided to ports: lengths were <|Input->15,Target->108|>.

During evaluation of In[377]:= Set::shape: Lists {trainedNet,lowestVal} and $Failed are not the same shape.

Out[377]= $Failed
```

Can anyone explain this error and how I can fix the problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that you have different numbers of data points for the "Input" port and the "Target" port. You can fix the problem by:

```
NetTrain[trainer, <|"Input" -> Transpose@features, 
  "Target" -> Transpose@weeklyReturns|>, {"TrainedNet", "LowestValidationLoss"},
  TargetDevice -> "GPU", MaxTrainingRounds -> 500000, 
 Method -> "ADAM", ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1], BatchSize -> 64]
```